# Implementing a python RTMP server, flash player reset connection after send media data, how to troubleshoot

Tags: python, flash, fixed, rtmp

I am working on a RTMP server based on Gevent.

Both RTMPDump and FFmpeg works well, but flash player always reset connection.

If there's any troubleshooting tools for RTMP, so i can at least know where is wrong.

Thank you very much.

**Update(2016-02-02):**

Seems it was a bug in setChunkSize, i used csid 8 but csid 2 is valid, connection reset fixed.

Bug still flash player don't play, maybe handshake is wrong.

Working on it...

**Update(2016-02-05):**

Finally found a solution, after fixed handshake follow by nginx-rtmp-mod, now flash player plays well.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Got a link to the rtmp stream so we can test? Maybe its just the code in your specific SWF (Flash) that is struggling while other systems can receive & play the audio/video...

Answer (score 1):

I would say your favourite tool should become Wireshark.
Because that's where you can monitor RTMP* messaging between the server and client, without need to decompile SWF on your end.

See an example screenshot from my similar answer to this:
[image]

Best Regards,

Eugene

Comment: Thanks, i have tried Wireshark to compare result with nginx-rtmp-mod.

Comment: hey @BeenWoo next thing you would want to pass all parameters from your SWFObject in a proper CLI line format for rtmpdump. See `-w` option here https://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/rtmpdump.1.html